# Local list users are not there in Global list lookup, So the local list is not visible for local list users?

Tags: list, lookup-column

I have an issue in sharepoint 2013,
I have a global list for lookup and that list has some confidential information's, so I am using few column as a lookup to my local list but the users in local list can't see the list because they don't have global list access. How can I solve this issue ? Please help me to solve this issue...

Comment: What do you mean by global & local list ? Parent Site (or Root Site) list & Sub site list ?

Comment: Yes, Global means Parent Site (or Root Site) list & Local means Sub site list

Comment: Assuming you are accomplishing cross-site lookups via a 3rd party solution, have you considered simply giving your users read access to the "global" list and then using item level permissions to secure specific list items?

Comment: But issue is, there are confidential data in the "global" list so I cant give the read access to the users.

Answer (score 0):

You can not create lookup column of Root Web list in Sub Web.
You can only create lookup for lists exists in same web.

Comment: But user with access in Root Web list can view the list items in Sub web list. Only issue is there when user with no access to Root web can't access Sub web list. What could be the reason and how to solve this

Comment: So, Are you able to create lookup column of root web list in sub web list when there is access given ??!!!!

Comment: Yes, When there is access given in root web list, user is able to access sub web list. But my issue is if I am giving access in root web they will be able to access confidential information's in the root list, That is an issue.